# Does limiting frames in dota 2 help to reduce power consumption GPU?

Tags: dota-2, performance, graphics-card

Does limiting frames in Dota 2 help to reduce power consumption GPU?  There is an option to limit the in-game FPS of Dota 2.  Does this reduce the GPU power consumption as well?

Would like to know since I want to buy a powerful GPU but I don't want the high power consumption.

Comment: You should be able to check this using something like [MSI Afterburner](https://www.msi.com/Landing/afterburner/graphics-cards) where you can observe your wattage before and after limiting the framerate.  But I find that in other games, by limiting the frame rate, it reduces the amount of GPU load, so it probably should.

Comment: i actually checked it and it looks like its lower but I want some feedback from other people.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, limiting the FPS helps to lower the load on your GPU and thus the power consumption.**

As long as the limiting action decreases the FPS, it lowers the work of your graphics card. It's as simple as "less work, less power". I.e. idling your OS takes your computer less power in acting/calculating parts like CPU and GPU -> less power drain overall.

Also, if you're interrested in limiting the power of your graphics card or GPU, you may search the web for "[Undervolting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_voltage_scaling)". This is often done with high end graphics cards to reduce noise, power drain and other possible unwanted side effects like coil noise.